# Xdebug is not getting enabled for PHP Version 7.0.1 in xampp

Tags: php, xampp, xdebug

I have tried to enable the xdebug for this specific php version by changing the php.ini [XDebug] code to required format as below. Still no changes in the phpinfo.

```
zend_extension = "\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-7.1-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1     
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"    
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"  
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

I have tried with both nts & ts (32/64) xdebug versions. Please anyone help me out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You definitely need to use the Thread Safe version and not the `nts` version
2. The XDEBUG extension must match the compiled version of your Apache and PHP i.e. if Apache/PHP are 32 bit then so must XDEBUG be 32bit
3. Try putting the drive letter into the zend_extension = `"C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-7.1-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll` line. Assuming your XAMPP is installed on `C:`
4. You also specify `PHP7.0.1` in the title but you are using the XDEBUG for PHP7.1 If you are really using `PHP7.0.1` then you need to use `php_xdebug-2.5.1-7.0-vc14.dll`

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly for the solutions.